# what is the best way to smooth the loop in a mesh like this

Tags: geometry, subdivision-surface

the loop in (and around) this object is very low-poly and I want to change that.

[image]

I have tried subdivision but that only causes more problems

[image]

this is what happens when I do Ctrl + V > Smooth Vertices

[image]

what should I do to properly smooth the loop?
[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10nkuRYpDQ40b12zvgVOew8g5gp8XJyxT/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: you could try the Ctrl V > Smooth Vertices?

Comment: didn't work too well. edited question to show the result

Comment: could you please share the object?

Comment: my bad, forgot to put the link in the post originally. it should be there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to shade smooth. Also maybe create a better topology, with no tris, like this one (I've mainly used the knife to edit your topology):

[image]

file: [image]

Comment: That's the issue. I don't really know how to make better topology the way you did. would you mind sharing your file so I can see what you did to it?

Comment: sure, I've edited my answer

Comment: Something weird with your object though, I can't apply its rotation...

Comment: i have noticed that about some related models. I ripped these from a game and all of the models from the game seem to be very messed up axis-wise or something like that. it has never really bothered me so I never tried to fix it.

Comment: oh ok it is parented to an armature, that why the rotation is messed up  ;)  just unparent it